# Print filename using regex in bash

Tags: linux, bash

With following command im printing out `*.crt, *.key, *.csr` files

```
for i in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -mtime +90 -type f -ls | egrep "crt|key|csr" | awk '{print $NF}'); do echo "FILE: $i" done
```

I have to check `*.crt` files to find out what kind of certificate is that, so im using following command to print out information that i need

`openssl x509 -in $i -issuer|head -1`

how can I ignore another files and execute `openssl` only for `crt` files inside my loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while IFS= read -rd '' file; do
    #do something with crt files
    if [[ $file = *.crt ]]; then
        echo "check cert"
    fi
    #do something with all files
    echo "$file"
done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime +90 \( -name "*.crt" -o -name "*.key" -o -name "*.csr" \) -print0)
```

Comment: If the OP only wants to check `*.crt` files, maybe take out the other `-o -name` arguments... though the question is decidedly unclear on this point.

Comment: @tripleee I understood the question that OP wants to do some actions with all files and do certain extra actions with `*.crt`. But you might be right, is it fairy unclear at this point :)

Comment: yeah i will do execute this script for all files and do something with `*.crt` files, i will give you feedback. Thanks for help

Comment: With the `-maxdepth 1` this is just `for file in ./*.{crt,key,csr}` in disguise anyway.

Comment: @tripleee I believe that would also match directories (I know the names are unlikely) but what is probably important to OP is `-mtime +90`.